# Git Branching in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I have two different projects, but some feature are same for both project. Both projects are commit to server as Master. I want to make configuration so that i can pull the selected changes of project 1 to project 2 but I want to keep remote of both projects different.

Note: I am new to git and I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can make patchs of the changes you want.
But, Why do you need to keep two git projects? You can keep one git project with two branchs.

Comment: Actually i am new to git. Now i am thinking to make it branch. But i don't know how to handle branches.